# Find the subsets of $\{ 1/k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that sum to one

Tags: recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Consider a finite set $\mathbb{A} = \{ \frac12, \frac13, \frac14... \frac1n \} $ and I want to find all of the subsets of $\mathbb{A}, \mathbb{B}$, such that $$\sum_{x_i \in \mathbb{B}} x_i = 1 $$

A trivial solution is $\frac12 + \frac13 + \frac16$. If $n$ is a number big like $50$, there are $2^{50}$ possible subsets of A. Not even a computer would be able to brute force all of the possible subsets. Is there a more efficient approach or an algorithm to find these sets faster? What if A didn't contain the sequence $\frac1x$ but something like $\frac1{x^2}$ or $\frac1{\ln{x}}$ or some other function? Is there an approach that can be generalized for $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Comment: Related search term: Egyptian fractions.

Comment: See [Egyptian Fractions for 1](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html#section9).

Comment: $$\mathbb B_j \mid \prod_{k \ne j} \mathbb B_k$$

Comment: Of course there is a more efficient algorithm than brute force: one can iterate lexicographically and prune whenever the partial sum is $>1$ or in the open interval $(1-1/n,1)$ or is similarly too small to be completed to 1.  I suspect this alone may be enough to enable $n=50$ to be searched in reasonable time, but further heuristics are possible.

Comment: For other sequences, you need to clarify whether $f$ is integer-valued since $\ln x$ certainly is not!  If you're adding irrational values together there will only be very limited occurrences where a finite number of them sum to $1$.

Comment: This OEIS entry enumerates the number of subsets for any $n$ up to $610$: http://oeis.org/A092670.  For $n=50$ there are only $10647$ subsets (including the trivial subset $\{1\}$).